# lorem ipsum generator for java, available in Maven Central?

Tags: java

Are you aware of any [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) text generators, available in Maven Central? I'm looking for an alternative to [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) from Apache commons-lang.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.sven-jacobs/loremipsum

Comment: Would be even nice if the words would be random.

Answer (score 8):

I created this a few months ago and added it to github. It's not huge and can also generate names for people

https://github.com/mdeanda/lorem

Comment: would be a useful tool, if you deploy it to Maven Central

Comment: It is available from Maven Central now.

Answer (score 1):

Search the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=lorem+ipsum). There are two versions, haven't tried any of them.

Answer (score -1):

"*[Datafaker](https://www.datafaker.net/)*" is a quite comprehensive library (currently over 230 fake data providers), and has a "Lorem Ipsum" generator named "***Lorem***".

Maven dependency definition:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.datafaker</groupId>
    <artifactId>datafaker</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Links:

- [code](https://github.com/datafaker-net/datafaker/)
- [javadoc](https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/net/datafaker/datafaker/1.8.0/datafaker-1.8.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html)

Note: "Datafaker" has initially started as a fork of "[java-faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)", the library I initially had recommended here with the "Lorem" data generator, and which seems to be abandoned.